# Configuring RollingFileAppenders for Multiple Packages Log4j2 .properties/.yaml, no .xml

Tags: spring, log4j2

This is my .properties file,

```
property.filename = logs/app.log
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = "%-5p %c{1} - %m%n
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yy}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{DATE} %-5p [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.rolling.append = true
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
logger.rolling.name = org.springframework.boot
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
logger.rolling.name = com.org.abc.package
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
rootLogger.level = fatal
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

The problem is im trying to explicitly set logging for two packages. But, this configuration does not work for both the packages. How do i configure logging for multiple packages using log4j2 properties or yaml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
loggers = springframework,application

logger.springframework.name = org.springframework.boot
logger.springframework.level = info
logger.springframework.appenderRefs = RollingFile
logger.springframework.additivity = true
logger.springframework.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

logger.application.name = com.abc.package
logger.application.level = debug
logger.application.appenderRefs = RollingFile
logger.application.additivity = false
logger.application.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Comment: That sounds awfully repetitive and bloated compared to the way it was configured in the old log4j; any idea of why they took this design choice?

Answer (score 1):

you have to define your loggers name in log4j2 file
Ex:
loggers = com.pkg, com.spring